# How to read xls data in PHP?

Tags: php

I just need a way to read xls data file:

```
frase  img
aaa    bbb
ccc    ddd
eee    fff
hhh    iii
jjj    kkk
```

I have just wrote this code:

```
<?php

require('spreadsheet-reader-master/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require('spreadsheet-reader-master/SpreadsheetReader.php');


if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{

    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

        foreach ($Reader as $Row)
        {
            print_r($Row);
        }

        echo 'File has been successfully Imported';
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload xls File';
}




?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head></head>
  <body>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
        <p class="help-block">Only Excel File Import.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>


  </body>
</html>
```

But when I import that file, I get this:

```
/membri/.dummy/temp/phpShRm3wArray ( [0] => ��ࡱ�;�� [1] =>  [2] => �������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������� ) Array ( [0] => ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Root Entry���������������������������������������������������������������� [1] => ) Array ( [0] =>  ���� ��������#$%&����(���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������� [1] => � �����\pCalc B�a�=���=@ 8�@�"��1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial�General���� � ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� �� � �+�� �� �)�� �� �,�� �� �*�� �� � [2] => �� �� ������������������`��Foglio1�''��T��Z�R�3��� [3] => �@@� ��Rfraseimgaaabbbcccdddeeefffhhhiiijjjkkk�cc ) Array ( [0] => [1] => � �d����MbP?_�%��*+�%"&C&"Times New Roman,Standard"&12&A,)&C&"Times New Roman,Standard"&12Pagina &P��&333333�?'333333�?(�-؂-��?)�-؂-��?�" [2] => d�,,333333�?333333�?U ) Array ( [0] => }�� ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] =>  [1] => � ) Array ( [0] =>  ) Array ( [0] => � ) Array ( [0] => �P�H��0�( [1] => � ) Array ( [0] => �>�@gg���� ) Array ( [0] => �� ) Array ( [0] => �����FMicrosoft Excel 97-TabelleBiff8�������Oh��+'��0 px������ [1] => � ) Array ( [0] => ��� ���1@�/ @@Hj�ػ�@����ػ�����՜.��+,��D��՜.��+,��\����Root Entry���������F@ ) Array ( [0] => Workbook�����CompObj��������IOle ) Array ( [0] => ������������!SummaryInformation(��������"8DocumentSummaryInformation8������������'t�������������������������������� ) File has been successfully Imported
```

Why?

Comment: check the encoding

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Could you explain? I am a little noob with the encoding stuff :D

Comment: check the files' encodings; all must match and seems that they might not all be set as UTF-8.

Comment: how can I check the files encodings?

Comment: Get yourself a code editor, one such as https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ that I use, and then open up the files. You will see their encoding type with a ball next to it under the "Encoding" dropdown menu. If they are not UTF-8, then you'd need to "Encoding/convert..." to that, and try both; either with or without the BOM (byte order mark). If there's anything that doesn't match like one is ANSI and another's source is UTF-8, then that too may cause that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner My terminal says this: $ file -i dati.xls 
dati.xls: application/vnd.ms-office; charset=binary